# Not able to ping Dialer1 interface

Tags: pppoe

I have setup a PPPoE server and client. I can't ping any IP address connected on the ISP router. I'm stil figuering out why that doesn't work. But the most simple problem currently is: I can't ping the locally connected Dialer1 interface. What is wrong?

```
hostname R1

interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0
 description R1 --> MLS1
 ip address 10.1.0.5 255.255.255.252
 negotiation auto

interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1
 description R1 --> ISP1
 no ip address
 speed 1000
 no negotiation auto
 pppoe enable
 pppoe-client dial-pool-number 1

interface GigabitEthernet0/0/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 negotiation auto

interface Dialer1
 ip address negotiated
 encapsulation ppp
 dialer pool 1

ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Dialer1
```

The Dialer1 interface does get an IP adress through PPPoE:

```
R1#sh ip int brief
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet0/0/0   10.1.0.5        YES NVRAM  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/0/1   unassigned      YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/0/2   unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0       unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
Dialer1                172.16.0.2      YES IPCP   up                    up      
Virtual-Access1        unassigned      YES unset  up                    up      
Virtual-Access2        unassigned      YES manual up                    up
```

Comment: What IP are you pinging from?

Comment: I'm running `ping 172.16.0.2` on R1 itself and it times out.

Comment: I have a similar issue in netlab after we change the router from 2901 to 4221 which is running IOS 16.9 while the 2901 was running 15.4.